# Creating an image gallery using tab thumbnails

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a component in angular that behaves [like](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tab_img_gallery.asp) a tab gallery.

My HTML implementation

```
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="display-container">
        <img id="mainImage" class="display-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.primaryImgUrl}}">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.primaryImgUrl}}" (click)="changeImg(this)">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.secondaryImgUrl}}" (click)="changeImg(this)">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.tertiaryImgUrl}}" (click)="changeImg(this)">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.quaternaryImgUrl}}" (click)="changeImg(this)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently trying out the (click) event binding and onclick which I dont think works in typescript.

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...// The usual
})
export class SingleArtGageGalleryComponent {

  public mainImg = document.getElementById("mainImg") as 
  HTMLImageElement;

  public changeImg(img:HTMLImageElement){
    let tempsrc = this.mainImg.src
    this.mainImg.src = img.src
    img.src = tempsrc
  }
}
```

Error recieved

> Type 'SingleArtGageGalleryComponent' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLImageElement': align, alt, border, complete, and 304 more.
> Argument of type 'SingleArtGageGalleryComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLImageElement'.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a type missmatch, your function `changeImg(img:HTMLImageElement)`
needs an `HTMLImageElement` what the `this` from your click Event Handler is giving is the Component your template belongs to, so `SingleArtGageGalleryComponent`.

What you want is a reference to the source of the clicked image.
The `click` EventHandler provides you with the Triggering Event, in this case a `PointerEvent` you can use this to get the target of the event and from there your `src`. This would look like this:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="display-container">
        <img id="mainImage" class="display-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.primaryImgUrl}}">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.primaryImgUrl}}" (click)="changeImg($event.target.src)">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.secondaryImgUrl}}" (click)="changeImg($event.target.src)">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.tertiaryImgUrl}}" (click)="changeImg($event.target.src)">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="{{this.ArtWork.quaternaryImgUrl}}" (click)="changeImg($event.target.src)">
    </div>
</div>
```

By then changing your `changeImg(img:HTMLImageElement)` like this:

```
  public changeImg(src: string){
    let tempsrc = this.mainImg.src
    this.mainImg.src = src
    img.src = tempsrc
  }
```

You can use the `scr` field.